# kSoap2 Android -- Cast Class Exception (SoapObject)

Tags: android, class, casting, ksoap2

I'm currently trying to retrieve an array from my webservice by using regular Ksoap implementation. However, when trying to access this array I am getting the following logcat error:

```
 04-27 00:27:01.772: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(530): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
 start activity ComponentInfo{android.waiter/android.waiter.TablesActivity}: 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive
```

It appears that for some reason Soap is not getting along with the way I am casting my property values. Attached is the problem code (and related methods)

```
public static TableDTO[] RetrieveFromSoap(SoapObject soap)
{
    TableDTO[] tables = new TableDTO[soap.getPropertyCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < tables.length-1; i++) {
        SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) soap.getProperty(i);
        TableDTO table = new TableDTO();
        table.setTableID(Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(0).toString())); 
        table.setCapacity(Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(1).toString()));
        table.setStatusFlag(pii.getProperty(2).toString());
        table.setCurrentWaiter(pii.getProperty(3).toString());
        tables[i] = table;
    }
    return tables;
}
```

TableDTO Information:

```
 @Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch(arg0)
    {
    case 0:
        return TableID;
    case 1:
        return Capacity;
    case 2:
        return StatusFlag;
    case 3:
        return currentWaiter;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(arg0){
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "TableID";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "Capacity";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "StatusFlag";
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "currentWaiter";
        break;
default:break;
    }       

}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object value) {
    switch(arg0)
    {
    case 0:
        TableID = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        Capacity = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 2:
        StatusFlag = value.toString();
        break;
    case 3:
        currentWaiter = value.toString();
        break;
    default :
        break;

    }

}
```

The problem is with the line

```
 SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) soap.getProperty(i);
```

It does not like the casting there. I'm at a loss on how to fix this.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Use

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Great answer, quick, easy and solved my problem. Thanks for the help!